# Why does ActiveRecord's delete_all fire single queries when inside transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this method:

```
# app/models/calendar.rb
has_many :events

def update_and_recreate_events
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    self.events.delete_all
    update(params)
    Event.import!(build_events)
  end
end
```

To make sure records are only deleted if the new records are valid and vice versa, I put the three methods inside a transaction.

`delete_all` should delete all records from the table with one query. However, since I use `delete_all` inside a transaction, it fires a single delete query per record. The log displays something like this for every single event in `events`:

```
SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1  [["id", 73391]]
```

I have no idea why it behaves like that, maybe I ran into some very basic mistake.

---

**Edit**

To avoid misinterpretation, consider this:

I don't want to delete *all records from the table* but all records which are *associated with the current object*. Therefore: `self.events.delete_all`

As the [documentation for `delete_all`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class) states:

> This is a single SQL DELETE statement that goes straight to the database, much more efficient than destroy_all.

Why doesn't it work in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

```
Event.delete_all
```

this will generate one line query

```
DELETE FROM "event";
```

I don't no why you are calling self since it referring to main object of Klass class.

Please explain more?

---

Update and trying to Answer

As I understand you need to add

```
has_many :events, dependent: :delete__all
```

Answer (score -3):

Because ActiveRecord using `DELETE FROM` for `delete_all` and `destroy_all` methods and that's the way this operator supposed to work.

For removing all table records with one query, SQL should using [TRUNCATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-truncate.html). Rails example looks like:

```
Model.connection_pool.with_connection { |c| c.truncate(Model.table_name) }
```

Comment: You've slightly misinterpreted the question I think. The OP isn't trying to remove _all_ records from the table but all matching records. They are expecting that to be done with a single `delete from` statement referencing all the events to be deleted rather than with multiple `delete from` calls per event.

Comment: @Shadwell I quote: "`delete_all` should delete all records from the table with one query.". But `delete from` doesn't work like that. Thanks for downvote.

Comment: Okay, that's fine, was just trying to help explain why you were getting down-voted. I hadn't down-voted until now.